# Remove Commas from String Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have string eg. ,,,,abc

```
   TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GV_Assoceries.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
   box2.text;
```

basically i am creating a new row of gridview by onclick event and settting a previous Data of a gridview row when each new row will be added then it will set the previous data of previous row, but don't know why i am getting commas in every string..

box2.text have a value ",,,,,abc" and i want to remove only commas from string, i don't want any looping to do this.

is there any function or method to remove the specific character from the string

Comment: You need to provide more informations to solve the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be slower, but it should definitely help

```
 string abc = "....abc";
 string trimmedResult = new String(abc.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
box2.text.Replace(",", String.Empty)
```

Comment: I doubt that this solves actual problem. It'll only affect the symptoms not the cause.

Comment: @StijnBernards: your answer doesn't refer to OP's actual problem either. Why are commas appended at all? It's like  repairing a wall to fix  problems with brakes of your car.

Comment: @TimSchmelter AH I mis read his question But yeah I'll update my answer once OP adds more information.

Comment: hi every one this one only replace the one time which means only one comma will be replaced not all commas

Comment: @SiddiqBaig My answer replaces all comma's but wasn't your question why your strings are getting comma's? Could you update your answer and add a bit more code?

Answer (score 1):

[Click me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you should refer to this.

MSDN Example

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String header = "* A Short String. *";
      Console.WriteLine(header);
      Console.WriteLine(header.Trim( new Char[] { ' ', '*', '.' } ));
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       * A Short String. * 
//       A Short String
```

Where new Char[] is an array of characters you want to remove form the string named header.